# Technical reason that specialized embryonic cells form

Tags: biochemistry, human-genetics, development

During the embryonic stage of human development, rapid cell division occurs and specialized cells form to build the various parts of the developing fetus.

I'm curious:

- Why technically do specialized cells (such as brain cells) form?  I suspect this is due to a DNA sequence, but why chemically / mechanically should a genetic combination cause a certain specialized cell-type to form?
- Have we (the international scientific community) reproduced the fundamental chemistry that causes any specialized cell-types to form?

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed chemical signaling that triggers the differenciation. There are gradients of chemical species during the development. Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphogen ! There are also other references there.

PS: there is a stack exchange question from today about something related [Can gap genes delay their expression?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/79805/can-gap-genes-delay-their-expression)